# Error: no classes specified while running javah on windows

Tags: android, android-ndk, native

I am trying to run the command

```
D:\workspace\FibbonacciNative>javah -jni -classpath bin\classes\ -d jni\com.example.fibbonaccinative.FibLib
```

but it gives error

```
Error: no classes specified
```

although I have supplied the correct classes folder. I am a newbie to the native android development so please figure out my mistake

Comment: you can try to bin/classes directory first. then, `javah -jni com.example.fibbonaccinative.FibLib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
javah -jni -o ./jni/FibbonacciNative.h -classpath bin\classes com.example.fibbonnaccinative.FibLib
```

Answer (score 0):

You've supplied the class folder and the class name at the same time in the -d parameter. That's not the correct syntax. As the message says.

Answer (score 0):

Can try like this also:

`javah -d jni -classpath ../../build/intermediates/classes/debug com.example.fibbonnaccinative.FibLib` (location of NDK file)